# Python pandas boxplot from dataframe

Tags: python, r, numpy, pandas

I have the following dataframe, which has a multiindex. I thought I could groupby run then create a boxplot to show the variance between the different runs, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
             beta
n   run 
n1  run1    -2.301871e-05
    run2     2.45619e-05
    run3     3.413542e-05
    run4     5.23709e-06
    run5     2.313496e-05
n2  run1     -2.96116e-06
    run2    -4.626588e-06
    run3    -4.463705e-06
    run4    -5.827251e-06
    run5    -3.127893e-06
n3  run1    -3.196585e-06
    run2    -3.020926e-06
    run3    -2.264738e-06
    run4    -6.599127e-07
    run5    -3.301398e-06
n4  run1    -3.509957e-07
    run2     -4.88517e-07
    run3     2.51758e-05
    run4     1.097775e-05
    run5    -9.213195e-07
n5  run1    -5.393409e-07
    run2    -1.147589e-06
    run3     -1.07985e-06
    run4     8.075297e-06
    run5     4.471477e-06
```

how do I create a boxplot from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
>>> df.reset_index().boxplot('beta', by='run')
```

[image: beta values by run]